# non-responsive academic program advisor/manager

Tags: advisor, academic-life, administration

My graduate program advisor/manager (one, who manages logistics of students; not for thesis) and I had arguments about how he proceeded the work (e.g. dropping my course without notice by self-speculation that my workloads are not achievable). Thus, I had arguments with my graduate program advisor/manager and resolved it during a face-to-face meeting.

Afterwards, I had a problem with working with him. He does not provide right information to my inquiry on a visa and has been ignoring my email inquires on a visa for over 3 months.

Following the advice from @Buffy, I involved my advisor to report the department and addressed this issue.

Comment: Is this someone who manages the teaching assignments only or do they also have some overview of your research? Does "dropped your course" mean a course you were supposed to teach? And how are they also responsible for visa issues?

Comment: Your edit makes it difficult to understand the problem and also difficult to interpret my answer.

Comment: Does this edit look okay with you?

Comment: Yes, thanks. It makes sense again. I hope it worked out in the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be an administrator level problem. Escalate it through the administration as necessary. And get your advisor to argue on your behalf. It seems odd that someone would disapprove a course that the advisor approves.

But there is probably a better advocate for the visa problem. If they aren't doing their job, escalation is warranted, and perhaps necessary.